# gmp_strval rounds to 0 instead of returning number that is close to 0 but not 0. PHP

Tags: php, gmp

Im trying to calculate probability (binomial) using large numbers since Im using factorials on large numbers.

But gmp_strval seems to be rounding to 0 all decimal values.

example:

```
var_dump(gmp_strval(gmp_mul('0.05', '0.002')));
```

prints: `string(1) "0"` should be `0.0001`

Now as an example im using small numbers but those small numbers are obtained by dividing large numbers using **gmp_div_q**

Any way to not round the numbers using **gmp_strval** ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider it a documentation bug. The GMP extensions for PHP work **ONLY** with integers. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-init.php).